# How to convert shortcode to widget?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I have a Shortcode with multiple parameters , like this

```
function recentpost_shortcode($atts, $content = null) { 
    global $post;   
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'post_type' => '',
        'headline_get' => '',
        'cat'     => '',
        'style'     => '',
        'num'     => '5',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
    ), $atts));     
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'cat'            => $cat,
        'posts_per_page' => $num,
        'order'          => $order,
        'orderby'        => $orderby,
        'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ),
    );  
    $output = '';
    $posts = get_posts($args);  
    $output .='<ul>';       
    foreach($posts as $post) {      
        setup_postdata($post);
        $output .='<li>'.esc_attr( get_the_title() ).'</li>';
    }
    
    $output .='</ul>';      
    wp_reset_postdata();    
    return  $output;    
}
add_shortcode('recentpost', 'recentpost_shortcode');
```

It is for displaying articles on the site
And I want to turn it into a widget
Is this possible and how?
Thanks

Comment: It's possible to convert this code into a widget, yes. Have you checked the official documentation on developing WordPress widgets yet? If not then this might help: [Widgets API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to convert the shortcode [recentpost] into a widget, correct?  This code has not been tested, but it should give you a starting point.  Basically, you register the widget, and then you call the shortcode (do_shortcode) under the public function.

```
//first register the widget (I am calling it recentpost_widget)
function recentpost_load_widget() {
  register_widget( 'recentpost_widget' );
}  
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'recentpost_load_widget' ); 

//Next We Create the Widget by Extending the current WP Class
class recentpost_widget extends WP_Widget { 
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct( 
     // Base ID of your widget
     'recentpost_widget',  
     // The widget name that will appear in UI
     __('Recent Posts', 'recentpost_widget_domain'),  
     // Widget description
     array( 'description' => __( 'Displays Most Recent Posts','recentpost_widget_domain' ), ));
} 

// Creating the widget front-end (what the user views) Using Your Short Code
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    echo do_shortcode( '[recentpost]');     
}
 
} // Class recent_widget ends here
```